# Functor of points $h_X$ is an fpqc sheaf on $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I want to show the following. Let $X$ be any scheme (say over the terminal object $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb{Z}$ in $\textbf{Sch}$) and $A \to B$ a faithfully flat ring homomorphism. Then

$$h_X(A) \to h_X(B) \stackrel{\longrightarrow}{_\longrightarrow} h_X( B\otimes_A B)$$

is an equalizer. I am being lazy here and denoting $\operatorname{Spec} A$ by just $A$, etc. Now the case when $X$ is affine is easy; this follows from the fact that the relevant Amitsur complex is acyclic when $A \to B$ is faithfully flat. However how can we reduce to the case that $X$ is affine? I have tried many things like assume $X$ is separated and $A \to B$ finite type to see if this works, and can come up with something. Is this result though true in general?

Comment: Do you mean $B\otimes_{A}B \stackrel{\rightarrow}{\rightarrow} B \rightarrow A$ is an co-equalizer in the category of schemes (identifying A with Spec(A)) or your diagram to be an equalizer in the category of sets. The first case should follow from the fact that tensor product is a pullback.

Comment: This was proven in a course I took in algebraic stacks recently. I wrote up some notes, and this sound like Lemma 5.19 and Lemma 5.20 here: http://folk.uio.no/fredrme/algstacks.pdf (I make no guarantee of it not being mistakes there!)

Answer (score 1):

The claim is true, but I don't know of any easy way of reducing to the affine case. There is some real work to be done here, in my opinion! See e.g. Theorem 2.55 in [Vistoli's notes](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf).